KODI Standalone: Second GUI App possible?
To my understanding, KODI uses GBM in standalone mode to display content without X11.
In my case: It should run on a minimal Debian system without desktop environment and as less X11 as possible.
I would like to occasionally have a second application (UxPlay) to output to the Same physical display. This App uses GStreamer sinks for output and seems only to provide output when a device is connected and otherwise idles in the background with no output.
What is the leanest way (in terms of less Software required) to have KODI running and overlaying UxPlay content when connected?
